# How to communicate to elaticsearch container by another container inside docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Below is my docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 9337ed510a0c # docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  importData:
    image: import_data_image
    #    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
         - elasticsearch
```

I want to access the elasticsearch service running by my import_data_image container. The import_data_image runs a python code which is supposed to create index in elasticsearch. To be able to do that it needs to communicate with the elsticsearch container. But I am getting the error:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2bdc8c3700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2bdc8c3700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)

How can i connect to the elasticsearch container running on port 9200?

Python Code :

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections

port="9200"
hosts = [{"host":'elasticsearch', "port": port}]
connections.create_connection(hosts=hosts, timeout=20)
```

Comment: your docker-compose.yml file seems ok. Would you post your python code?

Comment: What is the Elasticsearch URL you've configured in your application?  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that discusses the hostnames available for inter-container communication?

Comment: from python script which is run in importData container you have connect to "elasticsearch:9200" endpoint.

Comment: @danielarend I have added the Python Code. Please check

Comment: @akelsey yes i am trying the same way. Please check the code I have added

Comment: @aman why you write port as port not as 9200?

Comment: @akelsey port is a variabel that has "9200" as the value. I have updated the code

Comment: @aman - can you check from cli: "curl http://elasticsearch:9200" ?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#networks) in the your docker compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 9337ed510a0c # docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - mynet
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  importData:
    image: import_data_image
    #    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - mynet
    depends_on:
         - elasticsearch
networks:
   mynet:
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But the solution did not work for me. I am still facing the same error